# How to overload stream insertion operator with a template?

Tags: c++, templates, vector, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload the stream insertion operator so can I print std::vector to std::cout, but I'm having problem with syntax.

This is what I tried:

```
template<typename T> std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, std::vector<T> &v)
{
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(os, ', '));
    return os;
};
```

And I wanted to use it like this:

```
std::vector<float> v(3, 1.f);
std::cout << v;
```

What is the correct syntax for that kind of operator overloading?

Comment: Works for me... Except for the obvious `", "` instead of `', '`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is almost fine, however :

- The separator `', '` is incorrect : use `", "`
- Your function could (and should) take a const reference to v : `const std::vector<T> &v`
- There is an unnecessary `;` after the function close brace :)

For the record, `', '` is a [multi-character constant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aw8xdf2.aspx) of type `int` so the compiler complains that no overload of `std::ostream_iterator` constructor matches the argument list `'(std::ostream, int)'`.

Comment: I was so insecure in my c++ template syntax knowledge that I assumed I was making some big mistake... but it was trivial. Thank you very much. Fresh eyes see better.

Comment: just to add an explanation to what icecrime said, single quote is used to delimite _characters_ not _strings_ in C & C++

Comment: I save my source files as UTF-8 in Visual Studio so characters and string literals are always single byte.

Comment: It's standard C++ "An ordinary character literal that contains more than one c-char is a multicharacter literal. A multicharacter
literal has type int and implementation-defined value". The problem lies in your use of single quotes, not your source code format.